# return imageview (and know its position) selected by radio button in the same row in custom list android

Tags: android, android-listview, position, radio-button, imageview

I have custom list within each row have imageview,textview and radio button .
I select one radio button and i want to get the image of the same row of selected radio button.
I tried many times but no succeeded help me and i am a quite new user of android.

```
public class rowadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{
private final Activity context;
int layoutResourceId;    
private final String[] image_name;
private final Integer[] imageId;
int selectedPosition = -1;
int selectedimg=-1;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;


public rowadapter(Activity context,String[] image_name, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context,R.layout.item_listview, image_name);
    this.context = context;
    this.image_name = image_name;
    this.imageId = imageId;
     sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("position",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    backgroundholder holder = null ;
    View rowView=row;

        rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(image_name[position]);
        //holder.lvv=(ListView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);


        holder = new backgroundholder();    
        holder.radiobutton = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
        holder.radiobutton.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
        holder.radiobutton.setTag(position);
        int checkedpos=sharedPref.getInt("position",-1);
        if(checkedpos==position)
        {
           holder.radiobutton.setChecked(true);
        }
        holder.radiobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        public void onClick(View view)
              {
                  selectedPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();
                   RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)view;
                   if(radio.isChecked())
                   {
                   Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
                   editor.putInt("position", selectedPosition);
                   editor.commit();
                   }

                   Intent i=new Intent(getContext(), Preferences.class);
                   context.startActivity(i);
                   context.finish();
                  notifyDataSetInvalidated();

              }

          });        

   return rowView;

}
static class backgroundholder
{
    RadioButton radiobutton;
}

}

 //itemclass
   public class Item {
   String txt;
  Integer drawable;
   boolean checked;
  public Item(String txt,Integer drawable)
 {
this.txt=txt;
this.drawable=drawable;

 }
 public String gettxt()
{
return txt;

}
 public Integer getInteger()
{
return drawable;

}

public boolean ischecked()
{
return checked;

}
public void setchecked(boolean checked)
 {
this.checked=checked;
 }
}
          //mainactivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
 ListView list;
 String[] backgrounds = {
  "Metallic",
    "Wood",
    "Sea",
    "Garden",
    "Tiger",

 } ;
 Integer[] imageId = {
    R.drawable.metallic,
    R.drawable.wood,
    R.drawable.sea,
    R.drawable.garden,
    R.drawable.tiger,

};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.background);
  rowadapter adapter = new rowadapter(MainActivity.this, backgrounds, imageId);
  list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
      Button cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent go=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Preferences.class);
            startActivity(go);

        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: I´m not sure if this is the problem, but try to get the inflater in that way: getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: what is the relation of ur answer and my problem ?? can u explain more please ? @Opiatefuchs

Comment: difference is, that Activity(context) exists only at lifetime from activity, so it is possible to get null. By the way, in Your MainActivity at onClick, You are missing the @Override, or is this above just missed by copy the code?

Comment: @Override exist... but the line u wrote didnt make difference the main problem is to get the image of the same row of selected radiobtn